# Change the execution directory of a cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: maven, cxf

I'm building some tooling to (automatically) convert a large ANT project to a Maven structure. The project contains webservices. Therefore, I'm not able to change the input wsdl / xsd files. This is my input wsdl file. It contains a reference to a types definition from the poject base dir.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.test.com/test" name="Test">
    <wsdl:import namespace="http://schemas.test.com/test" location="./src/wsdl/Test.xsd"/>
    <wsdl:types>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This is my maven plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>                    
        <execution>                        
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>                        
            <configuration>                           
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlRoot>${project.build.directory}/../src/wsdl/</wsdlRoot>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Building the submodule works fine, since the cfx-codegen-plugin seems to take the ${project.basedir} as execution root directory.

However, when I try to build the complete multimodule project, the cfx-codegen-plugin seems to revert to the project.parent.basedir. I get the following build error:

Caused by : WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing './src/wsdl/Test.xsd'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\test\Desktop\multimod\src\wsdl\Test.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified)

Does anyone know how to:

1. Change the execution root dir of a plugin in a specific maven phase?
2. Or force the cfx-codegen-plugin to use an alternative execution root?

Thanks,
sjaak

Comment: What i don't understand is why are you using the ${project.build.directory} for the wsdlRoot, cause the default is src/wsdl/ as far as i know. Furthermore all examples on the page give ${basedir}/src/wsdl/... and configuration an not a relative path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It does not really matter. If I leave out the wsdlRoot all together (assume default) it gives the same effect. So: it buids correctly from the sub project. But it fails when building its multi-module parent (because its looking for the src/wsdl dir on the parent level). I cannot change the 'source' wsdl because a) there are a lot of these wsdl files in a lot of sub projects, b) they all belongs to an existing ant java project which I'm trying to convert to maven by writing tooling